# How to "add" field in asp.net application if i'm using windows authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i'm using Windows authentication in an Asp.net application, and it works great.
 The problem is that i need to distinguish between Admin user and simple user. 
How can i do ? 
Do i need to add a table in my database where i link active directory username and .. privilegs ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database aspnetdb that comes with your new 4.0 project in the app_data folder. if you dont see it you can click on the hammer on top of the solution explorer pane. from there you can manage users and roles.

add a new role called Admin

and in your code it can look like this :

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
```

Comment: I'm using mysql ... so i like my users can't avoid to re-inser user and password (windows/active directory authentication) .. but at the same time i need to differenciate them...